# html element.style.color question

Tags: javascript, html, colors, coding-style

I'm writing some javascript code to make some text blink but it wont work.

```
        function start_blink(elementId) {
            //var red = "#ff0000";
            //var white = "#000000";
            var element = document.getElementById(elementId);
            element.style.color == 'red';
            if(document.getElementById) {
                element.style.color = (element.style.color == 'red') ? 'white' : 'red';
                //document.write(element.style.color);
                blinkIntervalID = setInterval(start_blink, 1000, elementId);
            }
        }
```

It only turns red, never white, meaning that
`element.style.color == 'red'` always returns as false. 
Why is this the case?

Comment: First thing - change `setInterval` to `setTimeout` to prevent browser from crashing!!

Comment: `element.style.color == 'red'` returns true in Chrome when the color is just set to 'red' - http://jsfiddle.net/DdqZF/

Comment: Are calling this function at all?

Answer (score 3):

For a start this is wrong:

```
element.style.color == 'red'
```

should be "=" only. As you've written it this will be evaluated as an equality test, returning true or false.

Also, check what `element.style.color` actually returns, it might not be "red" or "white" but an `rgb` or `hex` code and may be browser dependent.

Thirdly, your use of setInterval is wrong. See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) for details on how to use this. You probably mean [setTimeout](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp):

```
setTimeout(function() { start_blink(elementId); }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is wrong in many ways... change the function to this instead:

```
function start_blink(elementId) {
    //var red = "#ff0000";
    //var white = "#000000";
    var element = document.getElementById(elementId);
    element.style.color = (element.style.color == 'red') ? 'white' : 'red';
    //document.write(element.style.color);
    blinkIntervalID = window.setTimeout(function() {
        start_blink(elementId);
    }, 1000);
}
```

And call it for the first time like this:

```
window.onload = function() {
    start_blink('MySpan');
};
```

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/KVBNB/1/).

Answer (score 1):

As has been pointed out already, you need to make sure that when you're setting a value that you use `=` rather than `==` which is used for comparing values.

Secondly, checking the colour value is going to be rather inconsistent depending on how the browser decides to interpret the colour (rgb, hex etc).

What you can do is count the number of times the method is executed and decide based on that.

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/nUvJV/

Here, instead of checking the colour we simply check the count:

```
item.style.color = (blinkCounter % 2)? '#000' : '#f00';
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you're attempting to set the element's color to red right before your `if`. If that's the case it should be:

```
element.style.color = 'red';
```

Not:

```
element.style.color == 'red';
```

**EDIT**

Yes, your logic was a bit off. [Here's a working Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/rLBTj/6/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="test">This is text</div>
```

**JS**

```
var myInterval = null;

function start_blink(elementId) {
    var element = document.getElementById(elementId);

    if (myInterval == null) {
        element.style.color = 'red';
        myInterval = setInterval(start_blink, 1000, elementId);
    }
    else {
        element.style.color = (element.style.color == 'red') ? 'white' : 'red';
    }
}

start_blink("test");
```

Comment: Oh, i see. In that case it does go to white, but it doesnt repeat. Is my setinterval function syntax correct?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried something like this and it worked :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Style change</title>
</head>
<body>
<p id ="stt" style="color: red"> HI MALLIK, I AM GONNA CHANGE MY STYLE !! </p>
<button id="butt" onclick="fontChange()">font change</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
function fontChange(){
    var line= document.getElementById('stt');
    line.style.fontSize = "30px";
    line.style.color = (line.style.color == "red") ? "blue" : "red";
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```